# Storing checklist results in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been racking my brains, but still can't think of a solution.

I'm creating a database for a checklist web app. Basically, a checklist is created and completed with options of either 'complete' or 'not complete', and then a report is generated which shows which items were not complete.

Currently, there is a table for a 'Checklist' that consists of many 'Checklist Items'. The results of the Checklist (whether they are complete or not complete) are to be stored in a table called 'Report', but this is where I need help. This is because I need to store whether they were marked as complete and not complete, and each checklist has a different length.

A possible solution is simply storing the unique ID of each 'Checklist Item' that isn't working in a string that could be stored in 'Report', with each ID separated by a comma. Each ID could then be extracted using PHP's 'explode' function, and this would probably work. However I don't think this is the most elegant solution, so any help to a better solution would be much appreciated.

**EDIT (Important):** The checklists are completed daily, and the reports are intended to be stored long term. Therefore adding a 'report' field to each item would not work.

Comment: Why not have a separate row in `Report` for each checklist item? why does it matter that some lists are longer than others?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to store both. Maybe you can store just the completed tasks?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @BeetleJuice Because the checklist is completed daily. If that approach was used, you'd have to duplicate the item each time or else the data for the 'Report' wouldn't be accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem damands a different setup:

- a table for checklists (id, name of checklist, ...)
- a table for checklist-items (checlistId, itemId, title, ...)

Now you can add a new table complete per checklist or per checklistitem. But for me a simple field on each of the above tables (TRUE or FALSE) should be enough.

EDIT

After reading the comments the table report should contain following fields
 - itemId
 - userId
 - (optional checklistId when items can be linked to multiple checklist)
 - (completed is always true)

A problem remains: what with items added to checklists after the completion.
A better solution is to add tables for checklists in progress (with the user that started it) and a link to the current completed items.

Comment: That would not work, because the checklist is completed many times (e.g. once a day). To do what you're suggesting would require the item to be recreated each time.

But the two tables (checklist, checklist-items) is already the case in my DB.

Comment: then just add the table complete with the fields checklistItemId, completed, date.

Comment: But I think we are missing some information. What are the different use cases: creating checklists, adding items, removing items, starting a checklist, completing items, ...  In this configuration you should save the started (in progress) checklists somewhere in the DB)

Comment: you've got the right idea. So, the checklists are stored. And the items are stored. But putting them in a report is the hard part.I'm thinking about making a seperate 'report entry' table, which has 'checklistItemId' and 'completed', like you suggested above. If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a checklisting in our company software (php framework built). It's simply a string based attribute `checklist` for an object. In that I save a JSON formated string which represent an array with checkbox elements. Each element itself is again an array containing `checked` (boolean 1 or 0) and `label` (actual checkbox label text). That works for me and maybe helps you as well :) Have a look at `jsonencode()` / `jsondecode()`.

To sort them just add another element `sort`.